# 80s Fantasy novel evil twin and swordplay

Tags: story-identification, novel

I once picked up a book in a bargain bin in the mid to late eighties, which I'd like to find again.

The story starts with a twin baby being stolen by evil creatures. A particular detail that sticks with me is that they fed him the breast of his nursemaid and the milk in it got him to like the taste of blood/raw human flesh (obviously paraphrasing here).

It then jumps ahead in time and the twins have grown up, one with the evil beings (demons? monsters?) and the other as a prince. He is highly trained in swordplay and much is  made of different named forms (think Rand in Robert Jordan). I'm pretty sure he had an experienced and wise trainer.

The lost brother returns I think and there is where it gets really hazy. 
I do remember that it must have been the start of a set because it ended on a bit of a cliffhanger I think.

I'm feeling a blue cover, guy with a sword... maybe on an outcrop of rock or battlement? Bad thing approaching?

Well that's my memory of almost 30 years ago! Does anyone know which book or perhaps even series this might be?

Comment: Hello Jason, welcome to [fantasy.se] and thank you for your question. If there's anything else you might remember, what the cover looked like for instance, you can [edit] your question to add those details. Meanwhile, may I invite you to take the [tour]?

Comment: @Jason: I notice that an anonymous edit was made to the post that looked like it was information that you added. If you lost access to your account, there's an account recovery link at https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: Oops, that was me, I was on another device and didn't consider that it might let me edit without logging in. New to this as you can tell.

Answer (score 7):

Found it trawling through a list of 80s Fantasy novels! It's *The Lost Prince* by Paul Edwin Zimmer.

[image: The Lost Prince]

> Were it not for the awesome power of the Hasturs, the creatures contained by the dark border would overrun mankind. As humans reeled from the constant onslaught only to rebound, the darkness searched for another path to victory. It stole a princeling and raised him in Shadow, teaching him what no human had ever learned. It taught him how to command the living and the dead, how to usurp his brother's throne through magic, and how to turn the humans against themselves. And then it sent him home...

[Rising shadow book list](https://www.risingshadow.net/library/book/24732-the-lost-prince)

The author was Marion Zimmerman Bradley's brother

> Paul Edwin Zimmer (1943–1997), the brother of science fiction and fantasy author Marion Zimmer Bradley, was a noted poet and an established author in his own right. He was also an accomplished swordsman who studied both eastern and western schools of the martial art and brought much of this knowledge to the books he wrote.

Comment: Should you return, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons!